# Not receiving notifications from Facebook Messenger

Tags: iphone, notifications, facebook

I have installed both the Facebook app and the Facebook Messenger app. When I am connected to the internet (either through wifi or data), I receive one notification per message.

When I am not connected to the wifi (or connected to spotty wifi), receive multiple messages from a single person, and then reconnect to wifi, I only see the last message in my notifications.

How can I get a notification for all messages, once I reconnect to the internet?

Scenarios:

Normal

```
Connected to wifi
Receive Facebook message 1
Get Facebook notification for message 1
Receive Facebook message 2
Get Facebook notification for message 2
```

Spotty wifi/No wifi when receiving messages

```
Receive Facebook message 1
Receive Facebook message 2
Connected to wifi
Get Facebook notification for message 2
```

(no notification for message 1)

Other apps, like the built-in iMessages app receive both notifications once wifi is reconnected.